# SAPNWRFC connection refused with no error description

Tags: qt, qt6, saprfc, netweaver

I have properly linked libs in my CMake:

```
set(SAPNWRFC_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/nwrfcsdk/include")
set(SAPNWRFC_LIB_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/nwrfcsdk/lib")
set(SAPNWRFC_LIB_FILES sapnwrfc.lib libsapucum.lib)

target_link_directories(appsap_rtf PRIVATE ${SAPNWRFC_LIB_DIR})

target_link_libraries(appsap_rtf
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
    PRIVATE ${SAPNWRFC_LIB_FILES})

qt_add_executable(appsap_rtf companyClient.cpp)
```

and then I tried a very basic example from **SAP NetWeaver RFC SDK**:

companyClient.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "nwrfcsdk/include/sapnwrfc.h"

void errorHandling(RFC_RC rc, SAP_UC* description, RFC_ERROR_INFO* errorInfo, RFC_CONNECTION_HANDLE connection){
    printfU(cU("%s: %d\n"), description, rc);
    printfU(cU("%s: %s\n"), errorInfo->key, errorInfo->message);
    // It's better to close the TCP/IP connection cleanly, than to just let the
    // backend get a "Connection reset by peer" error...
    if (connection != NULL) RfcCloseConnection(connection, errorInfo);

    exit(1);
}

//usage: companyClient <hostname> <system Number> <client> <user> <language> <password>
int mainU(int argc, SAP_UC** argv){
    RFC_RC rc = RFC_OK;
    RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER loginParams[6];
    RFC_ERROR_INFO errorInfo;
    RFC_CONNECTION_HANDLE connection;
    RFC_FUNCTION_DESC_HANDLE bapiCompanyDesc;
    RFC_FUNCTION_HANDLE bapiCompany;
    RFC_STRUCTURE_HANDLE returnStructure;
    SAP_UC message[221] = iU("");
    RFC_BYTE buffer[1105];
    unsigned utf8Len = 1105, resultLen;
    FILE* outFile;

    loginParams[0].name = cU("ashost"); loginParams[0].value = cU("****"); // hostname
    loginParams[1].name = cU("sysnr");  loginParams[1].value = cU("**");   // system number
    loginParams[2].name = cU("client"); loginParams[2].value = cU("***");  // client number
    loginParams[3].name = cU("user");   loginParams[3].value = cU("*****"); // username
    loginParams[4].name = cU("passwd"); loginParams[4].value = cU("*****");  // password
    loginParams[5].name = cU("lang");   loginParams[5].value = cU("EN");

    connection = RfcOpenConnection(loginParams, 6, &errorInfo);
    if (connection == NULL) errorHandling(rc, cU("Error during logon"), &errorInfo, NULL);

    bapiCompanyDesc = RfcGetFunctionDesc(connection, cU("BAPI_COMPANY_GETDETAIL"), &errorInfo);
    if (bapiCompanyDesc == NULL) errorHandling(rc, cU("Error during metadata lookup"), &errorInfo, connection);

    bapiCompany = RfcCreateFunction(bapiCompanyDesc, &errorInfo);

    // Use a company ID that does not exit. 000007 should not exist in most systems.
    RfcSetChars(bapiCompany, cU("COMPANYID"), cU("000007"), 6, &errorInfo);

    rc = RfcInvoke(connection, bapiCompany, &errorInfo);
    if (rc != RFC_OK) errorHandling(rc, cU("Error calling BAPI_COMPANY_GETDETAIL"), &errorInfo, connection);

    RfcGetStructure(bapiCompany, cU("RETURN"), &returnStructure, &errorInfo);
    RfcGetString(returnStructure, cU("MESSAGE"), message, 221, &resultLen, &errorInfo);
    RfcDestroyFunction(bapiCompany, &errorInfo);
    RfcCloseConnection(connection, NULL);

    // On Windows you can use the following function from windows.h toconvert to UTF-8:
    // utf8Len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, message, strlenU(message), buffer, 1105, NULL, NULL);
    // It will have a slightly better performance than RfcSAPUCToUTF8().
    
    // On 'system i' with Japanese double byte characters using the ASCII LIBSAPNRFC the
    // message string does not contain UNICODE but JIS encoded data. The call to the
    // following function does not make any sense in this case. Instead you can add an
    // encoding to the header lilke this: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"Shift-JIS\"?>\n<message>",
    // and fputs the message directly some lines below:
    // fwrite(buffer, 1, utf8Len, outFile); ==> fputs((char*)message, outFile);
    /*CCQ_SECURE_LIB_OK*/
    RfcSAPUCToUTF8(message,  strlenU(message), buffer, &utf8Len,  &resultLen, &errorInfo);

    outFile = fopenU(cU("message.xml"), cU("w"));
    if (!outFile) return 1;

    /*SAPUNICODEOK_STRINGCONST*/ /*SAPUNICODEOK_LIBFCT*/
    fputs("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<message>", outFile);
    /*SAPUNICODEOK_LIBFCT*/
    fwrite(buffer, 1, utf8Len, outFile); // See comment above for system i
    /*SAPUNICODEOK_STRINGCONST*/ /*SAPUNICODEOK_LIBFCT*/
    fputs("</message>", outFile);
    fclose(outFile);

    // Now view the message.xml file in a standard browser that supports UTF-8, and you should
    // be able to view the Japanese characters.

    return 0;
}
```

and the app always debugs only:

```
Error during logon: 0
R:
```

I'm 100% of the login data as I use them from other apps from same device (i.e. connecting **Excel VBA** to the **SAP RFC** directly without using this SDK connector).

The only difference is that other apps require the `loginParameter` also `system` (in the **SAP SDK** documentation it's as `sysid` or `r3name` or `dest`; I tried all of them, but same result).

How to find out why my connection is being refused with no error description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF this helps anyone, there was no reply and nor esults because i didnt compile as SAPwithUNICODE.
After I did in thr question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76970376/how-to-to-target-compile-definitions-in-cmake), I was able to either receive errors on whatever the program didnt like, or positive results

Answer (score 0):

SAP Note [2573953](https://me.sap.com/notes/2573953) describes which compiler and linker options to use when developing software with the SAP NetWeaver RFC SDK 7.50.