# How to to target_compile_definitions() in qmake?

Tags: cmake, qmake, definition, saprfc, sapnwrfc

In CMake I use:

```
#target_compile_definitions(appsap_rtf PRIVATE SAPwithUNICODE UNICODE _UNICODE SAPwithTHREADS)
target_compile_definitions(appsap_rtf PRIVATE SAPwithUNICODE)
target_compile_definitions(appsap_rtf PRIVATE UNICODE)
target_compile_definitions(appsap_rtf PRIVATE _UNICODE)
target_compile_definitions(appsap_rtf PRIVATE SAPwithTHREADS)
```

but how do I define these definitions in qmake?

Comment: So, you wont to pass compiler flags in QMake. Have you tried to **search** on that topic? See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980499/where-in-qt-creator-do-i-pass-arguments-to-a-compiler).

Comment: corret it suppose to be for CMake, let me fix the description.

Comment: yes, this quesiton was initialy realy for qmake... what I tried above didnt work, so I wanted to make an alternative in qmake to test something... not it orrectly fits qmake in topic header as well as description. Thank you for pointing out